# GtkTextView select all text on focus

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I'm trying to implement a text view that will have all the text selected when the user clicks on it. However, when I tried the following, the text isn't selected when the text view is clicked, although it is selected after dragging the window.

Consider this minimal example:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
gboolean cb(GtkWidget *tv, GdkEvent *event, gpointer user_data) {
    GtkTextBuffer *buf = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(tv));
    GtkTextIter start, end;
    gtk_text_buffer_get_start_iter(buf, &start);
    gtk_text_buffer_get_end_iter(buf, &end);
    gtk_text_buffer_select_range(buf, &start, &end);
    return FALSE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    GtkWidget *window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    GtkWidget *box1 = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), box1);

    GtkWidget *tv1 = gtk_text_view_new();
    GtkWidget *tv2 = gtk_text_view_new();
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box1), tv1, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box1), tv2, TRUE, TRUE, 0);

    GtkTextBuffer *buf1 = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(tv1));
    GtkTextBuffer *buf2 = gtk_text_view_get_buffer(GTK_TEXT_VIEW(tv2));
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buf1, "asdf", -1);
    gtk_text_buffer_set_text(buf2, "ghjkl", -1);

    g_signal_connect(tv2, "focus-in-event", G_CALLBACK(cb), NULL);

    gtk_widget_show(tv1);
    gtk_widget_show(tv2);
    gtk_widget_show(box1);
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

What should I change to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect the callback function to the `button-release-event` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I expect the `focus-in-event` isn't triggered when you click on the text view when it already has the input focus. Try using `button-press-event` instead.

Comment: False. It is triggered, evidenced from a `g_print()` statement I added in the callback.

Comment: Maybe you should return `TRUE` from the handler to stop the event; since the default handler is still getting called, perhaps that removes the selection.

Comment: Tried returning `TRUE` but that doesn't help. Tried the `button-press-event` but that's not working either. I then tried `button-release-event` and then it works. So if you would edit that into your answer I'd be happy to mark it as accepted.

Comment: I can't really take the credit for that answer. Feel free to answer your own question ;-)